# Manually updating App Widget [Android]

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget associated with the app. I don't want to update the widget on regular time interval but update it when onCreate() or onDestroy() methods in my main main app is called.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no concept of "main app" in Android, certainly not one that has `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` methods.

Also, note that `onDestroy()` is never guaranteed to be called on any `Activity` or `Service`.

All that being said, you are welcome to obtain an instance of `AppWidgetManager` (via the static `getInstance()` method) and call `updateAppWidget()` whenever you want.